# PHP in_array and if check not working

Tags: php

I've got a script and simple if check to see if a value is in a array. I can't seem to find out why the if tag runs when it's in the array.

```
else if (!in_array($type, $avatarformats)) {

$error .= '<div class="alert error">You\'re image is not a allowed format</div>';

unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

}
```

When the script reads $type and $avatarformats it's = to the following.

```
$avatarformats = Array ( [0] => .jpg [1] => .jpeg [2] => .png ) 

$type = .png
```

The if tag runs when it should not because .png is in the array. Or am I no understaind what am doing.

Comment: Could you do a `var_dump()` on those variables? Btw, you don't have to unlink the uploaded file, PHP does that automatically.

Comment: Works ok here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/zlcv6K. My guess (as Jack has alluded to) is that your variables do not contain the values you think

Comment: if the .png is string then give a try to $type = ".png";

Comment: @Jack actually, that depends on where temp upload files are located. It doesn't hurt to clean up unwanted temp files

Comment: I've print_r the array in the else if after the check runs and comes back true for both $type and $avatarformats and the values provided above should be the values as the if checks with.

Comment: if type is from $_FILES['userfile']['type'] then it will be  "image/png" not .png

Comment: @Phil Really? Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @Jack By default, they go to your OS's temp folder where they will be garbage collected by the OS. If you change the `upload_dir` for your app, you will need to clean up temp files yourself

Comment: @RandyPowell it would really help if you could edit your question to show the results of `var_dump($type, $avatarformats)`

Comment: @Phil The documentation states `The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.`

Comment: @Jack hmm, I seem to recall this not happening but maybe I'm wrong. Good find

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suspect that `in_array()` is returning true because the statement `!in_array($type, $avatarformats)` is evaluating to true due to the full stop. It is evaluating the value of `$type` as an integer because of the decimal place.

That being said you have 2 options: 
1) Try stripping the dot i.e. ".png" to "png" from the file extension before adding it to the array in the first place and then do the test.
2) or change your conditional to the following: `else if (in_array($type, $avatarformats) == false) {`

`in_array()` is a strange beast and I try to avoid it at the best of times. isset() is your friend and much faster than in_array under most conditions anyways.

Comment: else if (in_array($type, $avatarformats) == false) {

This seems to do the trick first time using in_array.

Comment: @jack what exactly are you trying to show me? that the OP code doesn't work? random neg giver. nice. Some explanation would be usefull...

Comment: `in_array` returns a boolean so `!in_array()` and `in_array() == false` are the same

Comment: Yeah thanks Phil. Strange how changing to == false works though hey ;-)

Comment: @Zappa It's showing that given the inputs of OP, the `in_array()` returns an expected result.

Comment: Why it works with the == beats me. Cause I always use ! I would of never guess in years to do it the same way with == false. It's working fully though I tested and everything works as should. I blame it on Ubuntu being a pain in the you no what.

Comment: @jack thanks for the explanation. I still don't believe its worth a neg though as I have personally had similar experiences with in_array (which is why I recommended that the OP tried == false). The fact that == false is meant to give the same result as !in_array() is fine on paper but in reality doesn't always work with this function (check the comments on the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php and you will see what I mean.) Perhaps its related to PHP version. Who knows.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you determined the type, but typically the `['type']` that comes from `$_FILES` is the content type (e.g. `'image/jpeg'`), rather than the extension of the filename itself.

To test for file extensions, you could use this code:

```
// get file extension (without leading period)
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// ...
elseif (!in_array($ext, array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'))) {
    // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Use exif_imagetype(), please read http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

```
function image_allowed($imgfile) {
  $types = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);
  return in_array(exif_imagetype($imgfile), $types);
}
```

Then in your code.

```
else if (!image_allowed($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {

$error .= '<div class="alert error">You\'re image is not a allowed format</div>';

unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

}
```